# Removing Ubuntu 15.1 and installing Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: format

I know just enough to get myself in trouble when it comes to computer stuffs.

I am trying to remove Ubuntu from my laptop (an Acer Aspire) and install Windows. If I put in the boot disk and select the disk as my boot device, I can access start up, but run into a problem. Something about how it can't install Windows onto the partition. (Two are available, the primary partition and one that has 1 MB of space. I don't know why.)

So I tried another method-formatting the hard drive. This also failed, as when I tried, I got the error:

```
Error unmounting /dev/sda1: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
 (udisks-error-quark, 14)
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I'm totally and utterly lost. Help?

I've reviewed other similar questions, and none explain how to deal with the problem I face here.

Answer (score 0):

See first of all if you want to uninstall Ubuntu and install windows then just put your disk which contains Windows into your disk driver and then reboot your system. When the windows installer asks you for disk selection select the disk in which you want your windows to be installed. And then format all the other partition into either FAT32 format or NTFS format. Let the windows installation complete. Your system will restart automatically with the version of Windows you have installed and Ubuntu will be removed from your computer.